# SQL Server Analysis Service passes null and blank values in dimension string attribute

Tags: ssas, data-warehouse, business-intelligence, dimension

It is expected in SSAS to show duplicate key error messages on null and blank values both in a nvarchar column.
We have a dimension that distinct values have some null and blank values in a nvarchar attribute. When it is in full process, SSAS doesn't show up any error message for duplicate key. Null processing is set to automatic and error configuration is on default. When the same table is added to a new project and the dimension is created, in full process mode it shows duplicate key error. However, it does not show the error in the main project.

It is highly appreciated for any help to handle this issue. Thanks.

Comment: Please improve your question - it's unclear what you are asking.

Comment: @RADO I updated the question. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know a long time has been passed, but just wanted to answer that may help someone. First off null and blank values must not be in a column in SSAS. So update blank values to null. Second adjust the Null Processing of that column to UnknownMember and then process.